# Delphi 7: deal with utf-8 data in JSON response read from website

Tags: json, http, delphi, utf-8

I am writing a Delphi 7 program to extract data from TMDB website using Indy 10 `TIdHTTP` client and lkJSON parser.

It works OK for ANSI-type data, but data with European accented characters appear as "?".

The output is an HTML page, so I was hoping just to leave the UTF-8 fields as they are. I probably fail at the first hurdle by doing `s:=Idhttp1.get(URL)` where `s` is of type `string`. The IDE shows `?` in the text, but that of itself would not be a problem.

How do I preserve or recreate the UTF-8 strings to pass to the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` occurs when Unicode characters are encoded to a charset that does not support them.

You are calling the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `String`. Since you are using a pre-Unicode version of Delphi, `String` is an alias for `AnsiString`, so `TIdHTTP` will

- receive the raw website data
- decode it to Unicode using the charset that is reported by the server (or a default charset if the server does not report one)
- re-encode that Unicode data to ANSI to put in the returned `AnsiString`.

What is the `TIdHTTP.Response.Charset` property set to when `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits? Make sure it is reporting UTF-8, or else data loss will occur during the decode to Unicode.

If that step is OK, then Indy's default ANSI encoding is US-ASCII by default, which means the Unicode will be re-encoded as ASCII, which will lose any non-ASCII characters. You can override that by using the optional `ADestEncoding` parameter of `TIdHTTP.Get()`, eg:

```pascal
s := Idhttp1.Get(URL, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
// s will always be UTF-8, even if the 
// original data was not UTF-8...
...
```

Alternatively, `TIdHTTP.Get()` has an overload that takes a `TStream` to write to, rather than return a `String`. It will output the raw HTML data exactly as the server sends it, eg:

```pascal
strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Idhttp1.Get(URL, strm);
  // use raw strm data as needed... 
finally
  strm.Free;
end;
```

Comment: `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` did the trick. Thanks v much. The JSON bit didn't interfere with the UTF-8 characters, and the database was already set to UTF-8